# How to declare a fixed size for an array in C++

Tags: c++

Quick and stupid question.
How do I declare the size for an array if I'm not allowed to use global variables?

Suppose I have the file `Album.h`:

```
class Album {
private:
    Song songs[MAX_SONGS];

    //...

}
```

where do I put `MAX_SONGS = 30`? 
`const int MAX_SONGS = 30`
is considered a variable right?
Please notice that the size should be known to the entire program.

Comment: `const int MAX_SONGS = 30;` is considered to be a `constant`. You could also use a `#define MAX_SONGS 30` pre-processor directive.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a container?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<Song>` and you don't have to define a max size.

Comment: I think there is no point in using a vector if the specs say MAX_SONGS must be 30. I'd prefer to use an identifier instead of writing 30 for code readability.

Answer (score 11):

```
class Album {
private:
    static const int MAX_SONGS = 100;
    Song songs[MAX_SONGS];

    //...
};
```

Note that inline initialization of static const variables is only allowed for those whose type is integral. Also note that regardless of initialization, this is still just a declaration and not the definition. You won't generally need the definition, although there are certain cases when you would.

As for the visibility, you can provide a static getter function that would return MAX_SONGS.

```
public:
static int GetMaxSongs() { return MAX_SONGS; }
```

Comment: `MAX_SONGS` must be `public`, per OP's requirement.

Comment: What about `std::array<Song, MAX_SONGS> songs;` --  then you can use `songs.size()` for querying, at no cost.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You'd still need a getter for the array itself, so it wouldn't be "at no cost".

Answer (score 3):

> `const int MAX_SONGS = 30` is considered a variable right?

Yes, `MAX_SONGS` is a variable, but it is a *constant* variable.  It can't change.

It's not so much that global variables are inadvisable, it's that global mutable state is inadvisable, if it can be avoided.  There is no mutable state here:  `MAX_SONGS` cannot change.

Comment: @PaulManta: Yes.  That is, in fact, what it is.

Comment: The more important point is that `MAX_SONGS` is a _constant expression_. Consider an alternative `extern const int MAX_SONGS;` with an initializer in some other TU would not be a _constant expression_ even if it is a constant variable.

Comment: I think the best way to do it is Armen's answer. What's the point of having the constant in every instance of the class? Wouldn't that bloat memory?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis 'Constant variable' makes no sense. Maybe 'constant object'? Or perhaps 'constant instance' is more C++-ish.

Comment: @PaulManta, yes, that is curious use of words. "If it can't vary, then how can it be called a *vari*able. Then again, why can their somes be an lvalue on the right hand side of an assignment? There are many funny things.

Comment: @PaulManta:  `MAX_SONGS` is an object and because it has a name it is a variable.  It is therefore a global variable and because it is const-qualified (and because, as Charles points out, it is initialized in its declaration) it is a constant.  It is, in fact, a _constant variable_.  @LuchianGrigore:  The OP implied that he intended to declare `MAX_SONGS` either at namespace scope or as a static class member (otherwise, there's no way to consider it a global variable at all).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis The term, 'constant variable', is nonesense. Is it variable or constant? Because it has a name, it's an object/ instance, not a variable.

Comment: I thought it was funny that "constant variable" is listed as an [oxymoron on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron). If you want to be pedantic, you should use just "constant", but who does that?

Comment: I'm going to ask the teacher if he meant that I can't use global variables, but I'm allowed to define global constants, but if he means variables in general, then I can't write a global `const int MAX_SONGS = 30`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `#define` preprocessor comand.

in Album.h

```
#define MAX_SONGS 30
```

in Album.cpp

```
#include "Album.h"
class Album {
private:
    Song songs[MAX_SONGS];
//...
}
```

Comment: Is the #define visible in other modules?

Comment: For that they must include Album.h. You could also make a Contants.h file and import that in Album.h and wherever it's needed

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `static` usage, use `enum`:

```
class Album {
    private:
        enum { MAX_SONGS = 30 };
        Song songs[MAX_SONGS];

        //...
    }
```